# como saber múltiplo de un numero en Python?

Tags: python

Me piden Escribí una función en Python que reciba un número natural n como parámetro, y retorne los primeros cincuenta (50) múltiplos de n . No se pueden usar listas.

yo lo hice pero me corrigieron que en lugar de usar print tengo que usar return y no se como modificar para que funcione si me darían una mano se los agradecería.

```
def multiplos(n1,n2):
    for i in range (n1, (n1*n2)+1, n1):
        print(str(i)) 

multiplos(5,50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo muy claro como se podría hacer sin añadirlos a una lista, se tendría que hacer así solo sea de manera no literal, las únicas formas que se me ocurren son 2:

Utilizar yield:

```
def multiplos(n1,n2):
    for i in range (n1, (n1*n2)+1, n1):
        yield i
```

En este caso la expresión Yield retornará cada uno de los multiplos pero en forma de iterable, es decir algo como una lista, para imprimirlos tendrás que recorrerlos de igual forma.

```
for i in multiplos(5,50):
    print(i)
```

Utilizar list comprehension:

```
def multiplos(n1,n2):
    return [i for i in range (n1, (n1*n2)+1, n1)]
    
print(multiplos(5,50))
```

En este caso se retornará la lista completa de números, de cierta manera el list comprehension también añade a una lista así que tampoco cumpliría tu condición, realmente la pregunta es un poco ambigua.

Answer (score 0):

Como no te especificas cómo devolverlos o en qué devolverlos, te propongo que devuelvas un conjunto. En es caso, es semejante a hacer una *list coprehension*, pero con conjuntos:

```
def multiplos(n1,n2):
    return { x for x in range(n1,n1*n2+1,n1) }
```

O, si quieres, con una función lambda que haga lo mismo:

```
 multiplos = lambda n1,n2: set(x for x in range(n1,n1*n2+1,n1))
```

Otra opción es hacer un generador:

```
def multiplos(n1,n2):
    for x in range(n1,n1*n2+1,n1):
        yield x
```

Ya después lo imprimes volviéndolo una lista o a través de un bucle.